# akka-http. Сгенерировать файл и отдать посетителю

Tags: scala, akka-http

Хола, коллеги!
Нужно положить строку в простой текстовый файл и отдать посетителю по определённому роуту:

```
def genFileRoute: Route =
    path("someresource" / "generate") {
        get {
            complete( genFile )
        }
    }
```

Но с реализацией генератора у меня затык:

```
def genFile = {
     val str = "Всем привет! Я строка, которую скоро положат файл и отдадут посетителю"

     // А вот дальше надо что-то написать :(
     // Что-то вроде 'php://output' с заголовками, только для акки
}
```

Как создать in-memory файл `file.txt`, не сохраняя в файловой системе? Как отправить его на скачивание браузеру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работу с заголовками мне подсказали [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817156/akka-http-generate-file-and-send-to-client)
Если вкратце, то нужно просто обернуть `complete` в такую конструкцию:

```
path("someresource" / "generate") {
  get {
    respondWithHeader(`Content-Disposition`(
        ContentDispositionTypes.attachment, Map("filename" -> "somefile.txt"))) {
      complete(genFile)
    }
  }
}
```

И полетит.